# Login and password field in wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching all over the web for this question that i think interest allot of word-press designers.

How do you get a login field and password in the word-press menu?

I have a login form that works in custom made pages. But how do i get it into the menu of wordpress.

I have tested different ways but the fares i came was it ended up in the header.

I did something like this

```
else  $link = echo '<form name="loginform" id="loginform-custom" action=" echo site_url( '/wp-login.php' ) " method="post">
    <p><input id="user_login" type="text" size="20" value="" name="log" placeholder="Username"></p>
    <p><input id="user_pass" type="password" size="20" value="" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p><input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" name="rememberme"> Remeber me</p>

    <p><input id="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Login" name="wp-submit"></p>
    <input type="hidden" value=" echo esc_attr( $redirect_to ); " name="redirect_to">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie">
    </form>';
```

Or is there another way of doing is?

///This is the form code for the login field.

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform-custom" action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-login.php' ); ?>" method="post">
<p><input id="user_login" type="text" size="20" value="" name="log" placeholder="Username"></p>
<p><input id="user_pass" type="password" size="20" value="" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"></p>
<p><input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" name="rememberme"> Remeber me</p>

<p><input id="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Login" name="wp-submit"></p>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $redirect_to ); ?>" name="redirect_to">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie">
</form>


/// Here is my script snippet. That adds an item to the menu.

function add_login_out_item_to_menu( $items, $args ){

    if( is_admin() ||  $args->theme_location != 'main-menu' )
        return $items; 

    $redirect = ( is_home() ) ? false : get_permalink();
    if( is_user_logged_in( ) )
        $link = '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( $redirect ) . '" title="' .  __( 'Logout' ) .'">' . __( 'Logout' ) . '</a>';


///This is where i need to change the href to my form code but i dont really understand how.

    else  $link = '<a href="' . wp_login_url( $redirect  ) . '" title="' .  __( 'Login' ) .'">' . __( 'Login' ) . '</a>';

 return $items = '<li id="1log-in-out-link" class="menu-item menu-type-link">'. $link . '</li>' . $items;
 }

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_out_item_to_menu', 52, 2 );
```

Comment: Did you try with wp_signon()? I think this function should work regardless of which page it's placed on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this ??

```
// This will filter through the menu items .
// Then append login/logout form to the end.

// add the filter 
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);

function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
        // start buffering
        ob_start();
        // this is the actual form function
        wp_login_form($args); // $args optional see below ..
        // get buffering
        $loginoutform = ob_get_contents();
        // clean buffering
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= $loginoutform ; // concatenate buffering with items ...
    return $items;
}
```

or if you want a more elaborated version to target specific menu ? 
Just add this to the beginning of the function

```
 if ( is_admin() || $args->theme_location != 'footer-menu' )
    return; 
    // change 'footer-menu' to the name of the menu you want to add the login links to. i.e. change to 'primary' to add links to the primary menu
```

This is more or less what you had in your question - But I think you might have misunderstood WHERE to put it .

This code goes into the `functions.php` of your theme - not in a specific page / template . it is a [filter ( read more )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)  - meaning it will automatically work ( "filter" ) the output and it needs to be hooked BEFORE the page / template is loaded .. hence - `functions.php`

**Edit I** - after comment

I think either I misunderstood your question - or you misunderstood my answer  ..

The method shown is a general filter for creating a menu item. It goes inside the `functions.php`.  Beside that code , you do not need nothing else .. ( except some css depending on your menu ).

Believe it or not - that code will make the form for you . Just copy and paste and see for yourself ... ( don´t forget to create a menu .. )

I cleaned the code - and added comments for you  to better understand , and these are the ( default and optional ) arguments you can use to customize the form .:

```
 $args = array(
        'echo' => true,
        'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username' => 'user_login',
        'id_password' => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
        'remember' => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false );
```

Please do try it and see if and how it works - you really not need to manually create the form like you did .

Comment: I already have it working with LOGIN and LOGOUT links in my menu. But what i am after is to replace it with login field and password field and a login button.  Inside the menu. So the login form is inside the menu itself and not just a "Login" link. I posted my loginform code that works on custom made pages in wordpress just for helping.

Comment: Thanks now it works perfect! I did a copy of the login function that is in general_templates and made a new login function with my own styling and put that in my theme functions. Very nice thank you so much!

Comment: ok. just remember to delete all the form that you had manually wrote ( or copied ). It is useless now with that function..